# I get turtle Maybe undefined warning

Tags: undefined, python-3.7, python-turtle

It's a turtle race program, but gives me a turtle MAYBE undefined warning on line 25.
When the line 25 if statement is not indented inside the for loop, gives the warning. If indented, it's fine.
I don't want to put it inside the for loop because it will check for the winner each time it loops.
AND what to do about the race on MAY BE undefined error

```
from turtle import Turtle, Screen
import random

screen = Screen()
screen.setup(width=500, height=400)
colors = ['red', 'blue', 'yellow', 'green', 'purple', 'pink']
y_cor = [-125, -75, -25, 25, 75, 125]
all_turtles = []

for cor in range(len(y_cor)):
    new_turtle = Turtle(shape="turtle")
    new_turtle.color(colors[cor])
    new_turtle.penup()
    new_turtle.goto(x=-250, y=y_cor[cor])
    all_turtles.append(new_turtle)

user_bet = screen.textinput(title="Make a bet", prompt="Which turtle do you think is going to win: ").lower()

if user_bet:
    race_on = True

while race_on:
    for turtle in all_turtles:
        turtle.fd(random.randint(1, 10))
    if turtle.xcor() > 230:  # turtle hit box is 40*40, so 250-20 = 230
        race_on = False
        winner = turtle.pencolor()
        if winner == user_bet:
            print(f"Congratulations, you were right. The winner is {winner}")
        else:
            print(f"Sorry, you lost the bet, the winner was {winner}, your guess was {user_bet}")

screen.exitonclick()
```

Answer (score 0):

`turtle` actually is indeed undefined and this code is not gonna work in this form.
So this name `turtle` is an arbitrary name of the variable which holds the element of the iterable you are looping through. It makes sense to us it only inside the loop, after the loop it's undefined.
Also are you aware, that with the indentations you currently have the loop only chooses the randint and does nothing else?

Comment: ok, got the undefined part, but if I put the if  statement inside the for loop, although it works, the first turtle (red), gets an unfair advantage because the condition is checked each time it loops, and the other turtles dont get a chance to take the next step. How about we use shuffle() function on the colors list, so we dont know which turtle moves first.